# shape matching in an autodesk dxf

Tags: python, autocad, dxf

I have a drawing (in dxf format) containing 9 different shapes arranged in a random pattern. I need to find the center point of each shape and derive it's x,y coordinate so that I can append it to a list for machining purposes.

The problem is I'm using autocad which saves each shape as a series of vertices even if I first convert them to distinct joined polylines. In other words, opening the drawing in a text editor just gives me a standard vertex list from which it's impossible to say where one shape ends and the next begins.

So far the only solutions I've had any success with seem awfully goldbergian. As an example I can export the dxf to a bmp and then use python and Opencv to identify each shape based on the number of contours it contains:

```
import sys

import numpy as np
import cv2

im = cv2.imread('drawing.bmp')
im3 = im.copy()

gray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(5,5),0)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blur,255,1,1,11,2)

contours0, hierarchy = cv2.findContours( thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = [cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 4, True) for cnt in contours0]
samples =  np.empty((0,100))
responses = []
keys = [i for i in range(30,90)]

for cnt in contours:
    tot = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
    [x,y,w,h] = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)

    if tot in range(1200,1250):
        cv2.putText(im,"shape 3",(x+(w/2),y+(h/2)),0,1,(0,255,0))

cv2.imshow('norm',im)
key = cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I could then take the output, scale it as necessary, and list the x,y. This is however incredibly time consuming and may ultimately lose too much precision to be usable (pixels aren't floats).

There has to be someway of finding these shapes just by reading the dxf otherwise autocad couldn't render them and I would just have a point cloud.

So how exactly does it know so I can tell python what to look for to identify a distinct shape when reading a dxf as a text file?

Comment: Looks like the start of a shape depends on the entity type but they all do end in "seqend". I suppose I could programmatically count the vertices between these, get the extents by finding the outlying most ones and then use this information to identify a shape as well as it's center point. If it works I'll post it as the answer. Still hopefull there's an easier way.